# Is it true that after the title (Mr), we have to add a name?

Tags: expression-choice

I want to know whether it's obligatory to add a name after *Mr*.
Can we call someone with "Hey, Mr!"?  Or should we should say "Mr John"? 
And if we don't want to mention the name, do we just say "Sir"?
And with *sir*, can we either leave it as it is or can we add a name after it?
Thank you

Comment: Americans certainly *used* to say things like *Hey Mister! Watch where you're going!* and *Excuse me, lady! You dropped your handkerchief!* But I suspect such usages are becoming less common (they were never common in British English).

Comment: I think 1920's era movies are required by law to depict newspaper boys shouting, "Hey Mister".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think in London, the people who would, in those times, have been addressed *Mister* would have been called *Guv*.

Comment: Using "mister" alone, as a pronoun of sorts, is possible, but the situations where it's idiomatically appropriate are rare.

Comment: Did you look up "mister" in a dictionary?

Comment: Hey, mister, is very old fashioned. Today, people are rude and you'd hear: Hey, guy (AE) or Oi, mate (BE). Apart from that, one would still  hear Mr. + first name in certain parts of the American South, Africa or the Caribbean as a sign of respect.....

Comment: You cannot abbreviate the word when it is not being used as a title. This is important, mister.

Answer (score 2):

In American English, you would always write out the word "mister" when used to address a man whose name you don't know, while its abbreviation would only be used with a name. For example,

> "Excuse me, mister. You just dropped your wallet."

Or,

> "Mr. Thompson, I believe you dropped your wallet."

The word "sir" stands on its own and may be used to address any man. For example,

> "Thank you, sir, for pointing out my mistake."

In American English, "sir" is generic and is a polite way to address any man, whether you know his name or not.

Comment: 'Mister' a pronoun?

Comment: "Thank you, sir, for pointing out my mistake." :-)